# C# - Is this how properties are supposed to be used?

Tags: c#

https://github.com/krgamestudios/Last-Ember/blob/master/Scripts/Managers/PauseManager.cs

```
//paused controller
bool paused = false;
public bool Paused {
    get {
        return paused;
    }
    set {
        paused = value;
        TriggerLists();
    }
}
```

I know you can do this: `Paused { get; set; }` (for what purpose I don't know). What I want to know is whether the above code is the best practice for properties with extra code in them.

Comment: Make the name of the backing field more distinct from the property name. Otherwise, mistakenly assigning to the backing field instead of the property (`paused = something;` vs. `Paused = something;`) is an error all too easily made and hard to see. Also, make the backing field private so it cannot be screwed with from outside the class.

Comment: Now, whether calling TriggerList() is an acceptable side-effect for this property, i don't know, since i don't know what TriggerList does (and no, i am not going to review the code behind the GitHub link). Side-effects of properties should be narrow in scope, not expensive in computation/performance/resource usage, and they should not do stuff that is unrelated to the value/state of the property.

Comment: @elgonzo First, the field and Property names follow C# coding conventions. This is how they recommend it. Second, the field IS private, so it cannot be screwed with outside the class. (but I would still write `private` explicitly)

Comment: @Dennis_E, There is no such common/standard coding convention as you try to make out. See MS' own documentation about properties:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties for a counter-example. With regard to private, yes you are right. Private is the default access modifier for members. I confused it with the default access modifier for (unnested) types which is internal. My bad ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in your example above, you are triggering additional action when setting a property value for your class, and is a good example of property usage. Another example is a property with only a "Get" accessor, for example

```
bool paused = false;
public bool Paused 
{
    get 
    {
        return paused;
    }
}

public void PlayMusic()
{
    paused = false;
    //Do other stuff to play music
}
```

So anytime you or someone else calls the PlayMusic() method, the private paused variable will be set to false; and the "Paused" property would let you directly know whether the state is paused. What's important is that someone cannot directly set a "Paused" state if you didn't want them to. It has to be a side effect of another action (in this case, PlayMusic())